# Como executar uma função após success do ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

No meu projeto, no success do ajax, estou fazendo um autocomplete, ai preciso executar uma função após selecionar uma opção, ou seja, após o success. Seria possível/Como eu faria isso?

Comment: Você pode usar `success: function(){}`

Comment: Já estou usando, quero criar uma função pra ser executada após o success

Comment: Você usar o complete, que é o último evento... porém ele é disparado tando no caso de sucesso quanto falha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Após o `success:` você tem o o `complete:` porém ele é disparado tanto no caso de sucesso quanto no caso de erro, por isso você precisa valisar o `xhr.status` para verificar se a requisição foi concluída com sucesso. Aqui no snnipet ela sempre retorna erro, mas é possível demonstrar a ordem dos eventos.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "#",
    error: function() {
      console.log("Falhou!");
    },
    success: function(data, xhr, textStatus) {
      console.log("Sucesso!");
    },
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
      console.log("Completo -> " + xhr.status + " - " + textStatus);
    }    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```